# angularjs - $httpbackend error: Unexpected request

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

I know that there are plenty of questions like this, but none of those worked for me and I don't really know what's going on and why they don't work on my specific case.

I'm trying to test a controller using $httpBackend.

Unfortunately, I always get

> Unexpected request: GET default-system.json
>
> No more request expected

The controller I'm trying to test loads data using the load() method of my factory:

```
angular.module('services', ['ngResource']).factory('myData', [
  '$http', '$stateParams', function($http, $stateParams) {
    var myData;
    myData= function(Data) {
      if (Data) {
        return this.setData(Data);
      }
    };
    myData.prototype = {
      setData: function(Data) {
        return angular.extend(this, Data);
      },
      load: function() {
        var scope;
        scope = this;
        return $http.get('default-system.json').success(function(Data) {
          return scope.setData(Data.data);
        }).error(function(err) {
          return console.error(err);
        });
      },
      filtered: function() {
        var scope;
        scope = this;
        return $http.get('default-system.json').success(function(Data) {
          return angular.forEach(Data.data, function(item) {
            var urlZoneId;
            urlZoneId = parseInt($stateParams.zoneID);
            if (item.iID === urlZoneId) {
              return scope.setData(item);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };
    return myData;
  }
])
```

this is the controller I'm trying to test:

```
angular.module('menuController', ['services']).controller('menu', [
  '$scope', 'myData', function($scope, myData) {
    $scope.test= new myData();
    $scope.test.load();
  }
]);
```

and this is the unit test:

```
describe('Controller: menu', function() {
  var $controller, $rootScope, myData, httpBackend, mockedRequest;

  mockedRequest = {
   "error": 0,
   "ts": 1456151050,
   "tm": "2016-02-22T14:24:10+0000",
   "data": [{....},{....}]
  ]};

  beforeEach(module('App'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    return $controller = _$controller_('menu', {
      $scope: $rootScope
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(inject((function($httpBackend, _myData_) {
    myData = _myData_.prototype;
    return httpBackend = $httpBackend;
  })));

  afterEach(function() {
    httpBackend.flush();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation(false);
    return httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  return it('Should check that the controller is injected correctly', function() {
    httpBackend.expectGET('default-system.json').respond(mockedRequest);
    return myData.load().then(function(result) {
      return console.log(result);
    });
  });
});
```

but I get the error mentioned above. Any ideas?

I'm really stuck and I can't figure out why it is not working.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: _"this is the controller I'm trying to test"_ Not with the code above.

Comment: Your controller already calls `load`. I don't understand the point of calling `load` explicitely in you test.

Comment: My scope in the controller is an empty object otherwise

Comment: If you want to test _"that the controller is injected correctly"_ then you have to create it after `httpBackend.expectGET`, not via `beforeEach(inject`. Or call `httpBackend.expectGET` within `beforeEach`, if possible.

Comment: yes, you are right. I moved $httpbackend above the scope creation and that worked. Thanks

Comment: @zeroflagL if you wanna put this as an answer I can accept it